# Valid node versions for Angular 4.0.0

Tags: angular

Specifically is 7.10.0 a valid version working with Angular 4.0.0.

Have been unable to locate documentation specifying accurate valid versions.

Answer (score 1):

I've had no problems so far using 7.10.0 with Angular CLI.

If you intend to contribute to the Angular project and hack on their source, here's their `"engines"` section of Angular's `package.json`:

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=6.9.5 <7.0.0",
  "npm": ">=3.10.7 <4.0.0",
  "yarn": ">=0.21.3 <0.22.0"
}
```

Comment: So that to me looks like they're saying that 7.10.0 isn't a valid version? I assumed that was just out of date and not useful since I'm having no issues with 6.9.3